# Magento Access functions from a module directly in another module's phtml file

Tags: magento, block

**My setup**

> I have two modules installed:
>
> - one takes an `id` and builds a product collection from this using the `id t`o lookup an `attribute-value` pair (`mod1`)
> - The other offers a way of narrowing a search down (`mod2`)
>
> The true url I am on is `/mod1/page/view/id/<id#>`

**Desired outcome**

> To be able to pass the attribute-value as a hidden field to the second module

**Question**

> How do I access the object and functions from `mod1` when I'm in the layout file for `mod2`?

If more information is required, please let me know.

Comment: Where is this happening?  Blocks, Models, Helpers, template files?  When you refer to the 'layout file', are you referring to the layout XML file?  Is there an observer in play?  Please reduce the question from a generalisation into a specific question with code samples if possible.

Comment: I have added the answer, is the question overly specific? Should I delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the module needed to be loaded was as follows:

```
Mage::registry('mod1_type');
```

Where in the controller this had been set:

```
$mod1Type = Mage::getModel('mod1/type')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($mod1TypeId);

Mage::register('mod1_type', $mod1Type);
```

Then I could use the defined methods normally.

This may be an overly specific issue, should I just delete the question?